# ent.sent.text in spacy returns labels instead of the sentence for NER problem

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, spacy, named-entity-recognition

I'm trying to solve a Name Entity Recognision(NER) Problem using SpaCy of the PDF files. I want to get the modal verbs(will, shall, should, must, etc..) from the pdf files.

I trained the data in spaCy. When predicting using the trained modal, the `ent.sent.text` attribute of the modal usualy returns the text or can say the sentence from which the label extracted. But in my case it returns the label itself not the sentence. Anyone help me please.

The codes are giving below:

## Code for data preparation

```
def load_training_data_from_csv(file_path):
    nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_md')
    train_data = []
    with open(file_path, 'r', encoding='cp1252') as f:
        reader = csv.DictReader(f)
        for row in reader:
            sentence = row['text']
            start, end = int(row['start']), int(row['end'])
            label = row['label']
            train_data.append((sentence, {"entities": [(start, end, label)]}))
            # Check the alignment
            from spacy.training import offsets_to_biluo_tags
            doc = nlp.make_doc(sentence)
            tags = offsets_to_biluo_tags(doc, [(start, end, label)])
            if '-' in tags:
                print(f"Warning: Misaligned entities in '{sentence}' with entities {[(start, end, label)]}")
    return train_data
```

## Training the model

```
def train_spacy_ner(train_data, n_iter=10):
    # Load the existing model
    nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_md')

    # Add the NER pipeline if it doesn't exist
    if "ner" not in nlp.pipe_names:
        ner = nlp.create_pipe("ner")
        nlp.add_pipe(ner, last=True)
    else:
        ner = nlp.get_pipe("ner")


    # Add the new label "CURRENCY" to the NER model
    ner.add_label("WILL")
    ner.add_label("SHALL")
    ner.add_label("MUST")


    # Train the NER model
    optimizer = nlp.begin_training()
    for i in range(n_iter):
        print("Epoch - ", i) if i % 2 == 0 or i == n_iter else None
        random.shuffle(train_data)
        losses = {}
        for text, annotations in train_data:
            doc = nlp.make_doc(text)
            example = spacy.training.Example.from_dict(doc, annotations)
            nlp.update([example], sgd=optimizer, losses=losses)
        print("loss : ", losses) if i % 2 == 0 or i == n_iter else None

    return nlp
```

## Calling the functions

```
# nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_md")
file_path = "/content/trainData.csv"
TRAIN_DATA = load_training_data_from_csv(file_path)

# Train the model
nlp = train_spacy_ner(TRAIN_DATA)
nlp.to_disk('custom_NER')
```

## Predicting using model (here is the problem starting)

```
import spacy

nlp = spacy.load('custom_NER')
text = "The language will be in english"

doc = nlp(text)
# print(doc.ents)
for ent in doc.ents:
  print(ent.sent.text, ent.start_char, ent.end_char, ent.label_)
```

`ent.sent.text` should return the sentence used above. But here the label itself is returing.

## Output getting

```
will 13 17 WILL
```

## Expecting output

```
The language will be in english 13 17 WILL
```

## Train Data

| Text | start | end | label |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| I will do the procedures | 2 | 6 | will |
| You should send the letters | 4 | 10 | should |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is that calling the below code. So remove it from the train function

```
#optimizer = nlp.begin_training()
```

which will also reinitialize all models. As a result, the parser (which performs the sentence splitting), will predict the sentence boundaries using a zeroed-out softmax layer and will start detecting a boundary after every token.

So, should remove the line that calls `begin_training`. Then later when you update the pipe, you can remove the `sgd` parameter and the pipe will create an optimizer internally:

```
nlp.update([example], losses=losses)
```

Comment: Don't you have to call begin_training or a similar function later? Can you elaborate on how you determined this solution?